# TypeError: 'Value' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, orange

thank you for your help.

I am working with Orange3 (and loving it)... I am aggregating large amounts of data and processing it for normalization, formatting and logical analysis.

I am using python to manipulate data in fields.

Here is a code snip:

```
new_data = in_data.copy()
        for d in new_data:
        for f in d.domain.attributes:
            #print(f)
            if f.name == "Phone":
                counter+=1

                inan = np.isnan(d["Phone"])
                print("NaN Check: " + str(inan))

                fph = str(phone_format(d["Phone"].value))

                print(str(counter) + ": " + fph)
                d[f]["Phone"]=str(fph)
```

TypeError: 'Value' object does not support item assignment

This is the offending line of code:
**d[f]["Phone"]=str(fph)**

Will someone kindly advise me of the correct? and pythonic (if possible) way to update the specific field during an iterative investigation?

Thanks in advance!

@objectAntics

Comment: I believe it is because you are trying to assign 1 value to the tuple. This is why it's giving an error. What is the data type of new_data?

Comment: This is an Orange3 Table   and I have not written directly to a field like this before. I know i can take the Tabel to a Pandas DF, modify the the Df and then write it back... but the overhead is huge,, I need to update the data Table on the fly.  
  class Orange.data.Table   as seen here https://docs.biolab.si//2/reference/rst/Orange.data.table.html¶

Comment: Also can you please correct the syntax in the code you mentioned? There is a function called append. Have you given it a shot? As per doc -Append = Append the given instance to the end of the table.

Comment: the append will not update the existing record, but in fact creates a new record

Comment: I do not know the correct code for this... syntax isnt the problem, the problem is that the methods to write to the object are set to read only (there is not setter exposed here yet)

Comment: If you want to modify values for Orange.data.Table, you will have to set the correct value in your new_data.X, which is 2D numpy table of floats. It can not contain strings. Strings in Orange.data.Table can only be stored as meta attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Marko Toplak this is directional enough that it may lead to a solution. I will let you know.

Comment: @MarkoToplak you were spot on... I had to modify the inputs to be meta/text and reload the file which made assignment possible. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @MarkoToplak

> If you want to modify values for Orange.data.Table, you will have to set the correct value in your new_data.X, which is 2D numpy table of floats. It can not contain strings. Strings in Orange.data.Table can only be stored as meta attributes. – Marko Toplak 8 hours ago <

@MarkoToplak you were spot on... I had to modify the inputs to be meta/text and reload the file which made assignment possible. THANK YOU! – objectAntics just now    Edit    Delete

new_data[counter]["Phone"] = fph